# Microservices Authorization best practices - .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, microservices

Migration of a Monolith to a micro service architecture. Below is the Authorization process prepared. However, I'd appreciate it very much to hear if the following will suffice or I may include more layers to secure the architecture.

Architecture contains:

1. `MasterAPIGateway` => Interacts with the UI, responsible for SSO
2. `FirstAPI, SecondAPI, ThirdAPI` => calls their Microservices
3. `FirstAPI` calls 3 micro services => `MSOne, MSTwo, MSThree`

`MasterAPIGateway` calls `FirstAPI`'s method passing `MasterAPIClientId`, `MasterAPISecret` in headers

```
FirstAPI/RequestAccess(Guid userId, payload) 
{
    // Checks if the MasterAPIClientId,MasterAPISecret is valid
    // generates H2HToken valid for 10 mints to be used by microservices.
}
```

`FirstAPI` is calling micro servies, passing H2H token, payload and UserID.

```
FirstAPI/MSOne(H2HToken, payload, userId)
{
    // validates the H2HToken
}

FirstAPI/MSTwo(H2HToken, payload, userId)
{
    // validate the H2HToken.
}
```

Thank you in advance. Looking forward to your ideas.

Comment: What is the question? And what is H2H?

Comment: @ToreNestenius Host to Host

Comment: Started to write an answer but it would be helpful with some more specific question.

Comment: as i understand your case you just need to implement identity server (ther are number of kinds like identityserver4 or you can implement with auth and oidc libraries by yourself ) instead of manually passing token. as @Tore Nestenius said reinventing the wheel. api gatway mostly performs reverse-proxy, load balancing , rate limitation, ssl ofloading etc rather than call specific service .this part i cannot understand from your description why api gateway itself calls specific services rather than forward request (proxy) to the services or maybe its an aggregator service.

Comment: @RouzbehZarandi May be you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73604622/microservice-architecture-structure-with-docker-compose-net-6 for details and give your feedback on authorization part.

Answer (score 0):

One comment is that the UserID might be included in the access token.

Often it can be useful to delegate the token generation and authentication to a separate service, like IdentityServer that all services depends on. Then you do not need to reinvent the wheel and invent your own crypto/authentication scheme. Better to depend on established trusted libraries and use JWT tokens.

Comment: So basically you are saying that ````FirstAPI```` can use the same service which is used by the ```MasterAPIGateway``` to validate the userId passed to it and generate a new token for its microservices.

Comment: In theory yes,  don't know how APIGateway is implemented or how you plan to implement SSO. but if you use JWT tokens everywhere, you don't need to pass username/password between services.  But if you have SSO, then you usually also get tokens at the same time, what SSO Service will you use?

Comment: Kindly refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73604622/microservice-architecture-structure-with-docker-compose-net-6 for getting a bigger picture of the Microservice architecture and I'd appreciate your comments.